# Order By con campo de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente desafío, tengo una consulta la cual me retorna los campos de una tabla y uno de esos campos es una subconsulta de otra tabla, la pregunta: ¿Es posible ordenar el resultado de la consulta usando dicho campo?. E intentado y obviamente no resulta.

```
SELECT
      s.idstock AS id,
      ...,
      ...,
      (SELECT sum(cantidad) FROM detalle_stock ds WHERE s.idstock = ds.id_detalle_stock) AS cant2,
FROM 
     stock s
WHERE 1 ORDER BY cant2 DESC;
```

Estoy abierto a alternativas si es que no es posible, ya sea a través de Vistas o alguna otra opción, gracias por cualquier aporte.

Comment: si no anda el order by competo, esto como subconulta de otra ordena lcanza

Comment: ¿Haz probado utilizando JOIN?

Comment: Coloca la consulta completa para analizarla. ¿Por qué usas una sub-consulta en vez de meter la tabla en el contexto mediante `JOIN`?

Comment: No uso Join, por que necesito la suma de las cantidades de la tabla detalle en la cual coinciden el numero de registro stock con el registro detalle; la consulta no es mas que eso, los campos de la tabla, tiene un par de joins, pero no intervienen en el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ordenar, el campo orden tiene que saber por cual campo ordenar.

Algunas version de mysql te dejan especificar la columna por su ordinal para ordenar

```
order by 3 --ordenaria por la tercer columnna
```

si no, puedes aclarar el campo por el cual ordenar, escribiendo el campo completo en el order by

```
order by (SELECT sum(cantidad) FROM detalle_stock ds WHERE s.idstock = ds.id_detalle_stock)
```

No te deja usar el alias en tu order by, porque el alias no existe si no hasta el final de tu consulta, y el procesamiento se hace antes de poner los alias.

Y si no, la opcion mas trivial seria:

```
select t.*
from (
    SELECT
        s.idstock AS id,
        ...,
        ...,
        (SELECT sum(cantidad) FROM detalle_stock ds WHERE s.idstock = ds.id_detalle_stock) AS cant2,
    FROM 
        stock s
    WHERE 1) as t
ORDER BY t.cant2 DESC;
```

Comment: Genial !!, muchas gracias funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizaria un JOIN, te quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT s.idstock AS id, sum(ds.cantidad) as cant2
FROM stock s
JOIN detalle_stock ds ON s.idstock = ds.id_detalle_stock
WHERE 1 -- NO ENTIENDO ESTA CONDICIÓN
ORDER BY ds.cantidad DESC;
```

Prueba y me cuentas. Saludos.

Comment: esto no ordena el sum... y le falta el group by... esto anda?

Comment: WHERE 1 es una manera de decir todos **la condición es siempre verdadera** Hago el comentario en respuesta a `-- no entiendo esta condición`

Comment: WHERE 1, le puse para no desviar el problema, la consulta tiene un WHERE pero no es relevante y tampoco interviene en el problema.